# pgfplots: "nodes near coords" on xbar chart is off

Tags: pgfplots, nodes-near-coords

I am trying to make an xbar chart using pgfplots, and I'd like to add the bar's value to the bar.

Simply using "nodes near coords" positions the value for a ybar chart, which isn't correct here. What's the best way to position these nodes?
[image]

My code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{filecontents}{my.dat}
Label     value       num
992       70          1
993       120         2
994       30          3
995       330         4
999       50          5
988       50          6
989       50          7
983       50          8
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xbar,
    xlabel=My value,
    ylabel=Label here,
    xmajorgrids=true,
    ytick=data,
    yticklabels from table={my.dat}{Label},
    nodes near coords,
]
    \addplot table [x=value, y=num]
    {my.dat};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can tell `pgfplots` to label the coordinates correctly by setting `nodes near coords align=horizontal`.

Comment: Interesting - that should have worked automatically for xbar. Probably a bug; I'll take a note to look into it.

Comment: Doesn't work for me...